# How to calculate distance between two coordinates (without floats)?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, gps, geospatial

I need to calculate distance between two coordinates (lon,lat) on embedded system which doesn't have floating point type (only integers available, so no trigonometric functions and no floating point operations like sqrt).

The points are very close to each other so accuracy is not an issue.

So I can not use [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). I also can not use this simple algorithm based on Pythagoras’ theorem and [equirectangular projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection):

```
x = Δlon * cos(lat)
y = Δlat
d = R * √(x² + y²)
```

Because I don't have cos and sqrt functions. Maybe I could implement them somehow, but this algorithm have to be fast (embedded system).

My best bet is Pythagoras’ theorem but how to get from degrees to meters without trigonometric functions (and without sqrt)?

Comment: You say "(without floats)" and that you don't have floating point operations-- do you mean that you only have integers to work with, or do you mean that you have floats and some set of operations (add, mul, maybe sub and div) but not sqrt and the trigs?

Comment: I only have integers to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally mariners would use Traverse Tables for this sort of computation -- see Chapter 24 of the [American Practical Navigator](http://msi.nga.mil/NGAPortal/MSI.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=msi_portal_page_62&pubCode=0002).  Which suggests that if `trig` and `sqrt` are out of the equation you might implement a lookup table -- trading space for complexity.  Depending on your precise needs you may only need a partial traverse table for the latitudes you are interested in.

Comment: That's good link (American Practical Navigator). I think it may help solve me my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you *do* have the sqrt function available to you. Check out [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number). It's not perfect, given that you've apparently got just integers to work with, which I'm taking to mean that your mantissas'll get chopped off at each step, but it's an option. There are also other square root approximations out there, as well. (To implement the cosine function, perhaps you could use a Taylor approximation, but I'm not sure how well that'd work here.)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase, taxicab / cityblock distance may be helpfull:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score -1):

Each degree on earth is 111133.333 metres.

How you can get there without sqrt is another matter! I am at a bit of a loss to think what system/software are you using which doesn't have this basic mathematical functionality?

You can get around the floating point issue by raising everything to the power of say 1000. That's what we used to have to do with Java ME (if I remember correctly!!!)

Comment: "Historically, the metre was defined by the French Academy of Sciences as the length between two marks on a platinum-iridium bar, which was designed to represent 1/10,000,000 of the distance from the equator to the north pole through Paris" so yes, 1 degree of latitude is ~111133.333 meters and it is usually from ~104-113 km (low error). But 1 degree of longitude is more variable...

Comment: Embedded systems or DSPs very often doesn't have floating point computations. It's not so basic as it seems for humans :)

Comment: This answer is misleading.  As a counter argument to the first statement, the length of a degree of longitude at high latitudes may be much smaller than suggested, since it vanishes to 0 at +/- 90deg. It is well known to navigators that the length of a degree of latitude is not constant either. And I think @Christy Herron means 'multiply by 1000' rather than 'raise to the power of 1000'.  Why even the former approach is of interest on a machine without floating-point arithmetic in the first place, I'm not sure.

Comment: @High Performance Mark, sorry your right - I should made myself more clear. A degree at the equator is 111133.333 metres. As for multiplying by 1000; I just meant that you should reduce your unit of measurement. So, using millimetres instead of metres is a way around the floating point issue